# How to use serial-perl tool of contiki to write output of mote in file along with timestamp?

Tags: contiki

I want to save output of a mote in a text file along with timestamp. Can someone show how to use "serial-perl" tool of Contiki?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `serial-log.pl` if that's what you mean and don't recommend it. It's removed from newer versions such as Contiki-NG.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `serialdump` tool in the `sky` or its upgrade in the `jn516x` folder to dump messages from the serial port. `-T` flag enables logging of timestamps. After the flag, format can be specified, for example `-T%s` logs the UNIX timestamp in seconds.

```
./sky/serialdump-linux -b115200 -T%s /dev/ttyUSB0 > file.log
```